# Number of permutations under restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I need to find how many permutations are there of the letters in:

**eeeddnntsc** such that beside each **n** there is **d**

well i tried with a warm up saying that total permutations for the word:

$$ \left(\frac{10!}{2!*2!*3!}\right) $$

lets assume that i stick **dn** together, which means we now have **7** letters.

the total permutations:

$$ \left(\frac{8!*2^2}{2!*3!}\right) $$

the $2^2$ is for ordering the two pairs of **dn** and the 3! and 2! are for avoiding duplications.

I still however, unhappy with the outcome.

any thoughts?

much appreciation

Comment: @Masacroso It is the letters of the word "descendant" that are permuted. OP never indicated that the string "descendant" would count.

Comment: The outcome you took is correct, why are you unhappy?

Comment: exactly as amWhy wrote. that's how the question was written. If it's confusing, then how many permutations are there such that beside each *n* there is *d* using :   e ( 3 times ) n ( twice ) d ( twice ) t , s ( 1 time each )

Comment: I am afraid we have a scenario which is missing : note that ndn is also a valid permutation while the other d can be wherever. i guess i need to take care for it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three $e's$, two each of $d$ and $n$, and one each of $s,c,t$.

Leave out the two $d's$ for the moment

There are a total of $\dfrac{8!}{3!2!} = 3360$ permutations with $\dfrac{7!}{3!} = 840$ having the $n's$ together

In the former case, there are $2$ places for each $d$, thus $(3360-840)\times 4$ ways

In the latter case, one $d$ *must* be placed in between the two $n's$,
and the other has $10$ places, thus $840\times 10$ ways

Add up.

Answer (score 1):

@true blue anil,

Thanks a lot for the explanation and solution!

would you consider my updated solution valid as well? :

$$\left(\frac{8!2^2}{2!3!}\right) +\left(\frac{2*6*6!}{3!}\right)+ \left(\frac{6*5*6!}{3!}\right) $$

explanations:

$\left(\frac{8!2^2}{2!3!}\right)$ - permutations such that ***dn*** is considered a letter and glued together.

$\left(\frac{2*6*6!}{3!}\right)$ - permutations such that ***ndn*** is considered a letter and it opens or closes the permutation. 
2 stands for where **ndn** is , 6 - choosing where the other d is, ( must not be beside the **ndn**, 6! for the rest without restriction )

$\left(\frac{6*5*6!}{3!}\right)$ - permutations such that ***ndn*** is considered a letter and it isn't opening or closing the permutation. 6 stands for where **ndn** is, 5 - choosing where the other d is, ( must not be beside the **ndn** of each side, 6! for the rest without restriction )

Tom

Comment: This is fine , there is more than one way to skin a cat ! :) Btw, if you write someone's name in an answer, the person doesn't receive the message..

Comment: Correcting the omission to mark you up for tackling the problem in your way! :)